# How to implement TileWindows algorithm in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fill some square evenly with divs. It is allowed to adjust div's width and height. I know that WINAPI has a function, named TileWindows (described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554(v=vs.85).aspx), but I need to implement the same behavior in JavaScript. So, how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how this tileWindows function works. Can you give more information? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Jonas Grumann, it fills the square with windows. It might get an argument that determines the priority: horizontal or vertical. If horizontal then function will try to fill square with windows where the width will be lagrer than height and vise versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invented by myself.

**Notices:**

1) `clientRect` is a square object, returned by `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

2) `dialogs` is an Array of objects that we need to place inside the square. (were just dialog windows in my case). I implemented the methods like setTop, setWidth, setLeft, setHeight, but you can use just `element.style.top = top + 'px';` etc.

```
function tileHorizontalDialogs(clientRect, dialogs) {
        var dialogsCount = dialogs.length;
        var top = clientRect.top;
        var left = clientRect.left;
        var XC = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(dialogsCount));
        var YC = Math.floor(dialogsCount / XC);
        var w = clientRect.width / XC;
        var h0 = clientRect.height / YC;
        var h1 = clientRect.height / (YC + 1);
        var modulo = dialogsCount % XC;
        var firstExtendedColumnNumber = XC - modulo + 1;
        var d = 0;
        for (var hIterator = 1; hIterator <= XC; hIterator++) {
            var h = 0;
            var vLimit = 0;
            if (hIterator < firstExtendedColumnNumber) {
                vLimit = YC;
                h = h0;
            }
            else if (hIterator >= firstExtendedColumnNumber) {
                vLimit = YC + 1;
                h = h1;
            }
            for (var vIterator = 1; vIterator <= vLimit; vIterator++) {
                dialogs[d].setTop(top);
                dialogs[d].setLeft(left);
                dialogs[d].setWidth(w);
                dialogs[d].setHeight(h);
                top += h;
                d++;
            }
            top = clientRect.top;
            left += w;
        }
    };
function tileVerticalDialogs(clientRect, dialogs) {
        var dialogsCount = dialogs.length;
        var top = clientRect.top;
        var left = clientRect.left;
        var YC = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(dialogsCount));
        var XC = Math.floor(dialogsCount / YC);
        var h = clientRect.height / YC;
        var w0 = clientRect.width / XC;
        var w1 = clientRect.width / (XC + 1);
        var modulo = dialogsCount % YC;
        var firstExtendedRowNumber = YC - modulo + 1;
        var d = 0;
        for (var vIterator = 1; vIterator <= YC; vIterator++) {
            var w = 0;
            var hLimit = 0;
            if (vIterator < firstExtendedRowNumber) {
                hLimit = XC;
                w = w0;
            }
            else if (vIterator >= firstExtendedRowNumber) {
                hLimit = XC + 1;
                w = w1;
            }
            for (var hIterator = 1; hIterator <= hLimit; hIterator++) {
                dialogs[d].setTop(top);
                dialogs[d].setLeft(left);
                dialogs[d].setWidth(w);
                dialogs[d].setHeight(h);
                left += w;
                d++;
            }
            left = clientRect.left;
            top += h;
        }
    };
```